# CSS grid item always on a single line

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to create a simple layout: there are some labels that have to be placed on different lines because there isn't enough space for all.
I use Grid to do this.

[My code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xNjdaq) works but I prefer that each label should be on a single line.

Now:

[image]

The label `a very very very very long label` should be on a single line not on two.

The code:

```css
.container {
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
  grid-gap: 5px 5px;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">apple</div>
  <div class="child">social</div>
  <div class="child">cat</div>
  <div class="child">computer</div>
  <div class="child">table</div>
  <div class="child">photograph</div>
  <div class="child">future of the world</div>
  <div class="child">something</div>
  <div class="child">yellow</div>
  <div class="child">romance</div>
  <div class="child">dictionary</div>
  <div class="child">a very very very very long label</div>
</div>
```

How can I have to change my code?

---

In [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/joxKzR) I use the code posted by @Saksham and I change only `text-align` from `center` to `left`.

Changing windows size I get this:

[image]

But I want this:

[image]

As you can see, there is less free space around `dictionary` and `a very very very very long label` labels

Comment: `white-space: nowrap`?

Comment: your code snippet is showing on 1 line, looks correct on chrome

Comment: i would suggest you to use regular `inline-block` elements for this as the box for "social" is unnecessarily taking up space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather advice you to switch to `flexbox`. Your tiles are unnecessarily taking up space if a vertically placed tile has more text.

```css
.container {
  background-color: #aaa;
  width:400px;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container:after {
  flex: auto;
  content:'';
  flex-grow: 100;
}

.child {
  margin: 2px 1px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #888;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex:1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">apple</div>
  <div class="child">social</div>
  <div class="child">cat</div>
  <div class="child">computer</div>
  <div class="child">table</div>
  <div class="child">photograph</div>
  <div class="child">future of the world</div>
  <div class="child">something</div>
  <div class="child">yellow</div>
  <div class="child">romance</div>
  <div class="child">dictionary</div>
  <div class="child">a very very very very long label</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! There is a way to have label container width always as label width and not longer than the text? Now there is an extra space

Comment: @sleepwalking can you explain in detail. Are you asking or telling me?

Comment: @sleepwalking I have updated the solution to specify the `flex` property with a large number so that it takes up all the available space.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `max-content` instead of `auto` in your column definition - and to adjust for the overflow of the `container` (if some screen widths) you may use `overflow: auto` - change screen width and check the demo below:

```css
.container {
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, max-content); /* added */
  grid-gap: 5px 5px;
   overflow: auto; /* handle overflow if needed */
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">apple</div>
  <div class="child">social</div>
  <div class="child">cat</div>
  <div class="child">computer</div>
  <div class="child">table</div>
  <div class="child">photograph</div>
  <div class="child">future of the world</div>
  <div class="child">something</div>
  <div class="child">yellow</div>
  <div class="child">romance</div>
  <div class="child">dictionary</div>
  <div class="child">a very very very very long label</div>
</div>
```

If you want the columns to share the available viewport space horizontally, you can also use the `minmax` function like `grid-template-columns: repeat(5, minmax(max-content, 1fr))`:

```css
.container {
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, minmax(max-content, 1fr)); /* added */
  grid-gap: 5px 5px;
   overflow: auto; /* handle overflow if needed */
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">apple</div>
  <div class="child">social</div>
  <div class="child">cat</div>
  <div class="child">computer</div>
  <div class="child">table</div>
  <div class="child">photograph</div>
  <div class="child">future of the world</div>
  <div class="child">something</div>
  <div class="child">yellow</div>
  <div class="child">romance</div>
  <div class="child">dictionary</div>
  <div class="child">a very very very very long label</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but in your case, layout is not responsive

Answer (score -2):

What do you mean on a single line? If you mean a line break just add the following

```
    <br>
```

If you want the content of the cell to be on a single line, try using overflow

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp
This might be helpful.

Comment: OP means he wants the entire grid to show as a single row; in the attached screenshot, it's broken into several rows.

Comment: Then the link will solve the problem. I just tested it out and it works. Just change the css .child to the following

Comment: .child {
  
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: scroll;
}